# Find out min, max and avg value

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I want to get value of these Aggregate functions min(), max(), and avg() within single laravel Eloquent object relational mapper?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself that we can see?

Answer (score 1):

Try $object->relation()->max('field') the same for the others